# Change in Notifications preference of app in Settings app(default iPhone app)

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

My app is successfully registered for remote push notification using `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` and this results in adding notification preference entry for my app in 'Settings-->Notification Center' of device. Let say, alert type is set  `UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge`.

***Questions*** : If user changes notification preference of my app in Settings from `UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge` to `UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone`, is there anyway my app gets indication of this changes **at runtime**? Like the app adds itself as an observer using `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver......]` for the system wide setting change?

I couldn't get any information from apple document for the above mentioned scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Depend from the type of information, for example to know if the user disabled notifications or just some type of, you can just use:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
    //User disabled notifications
}
```

The type are:

```
UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone    = 0,
UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge   = 1 << 0,
UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound   = 1 << 1,
UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert   = 1 << 2,
UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability = 1 << 3
```

Comment: I'd like my app to be notified when user changes notification preference in settings dynamically (at runtime). I'm aware of checks you mentioned in your answer, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: at runtime?? when an user is in the setting he is not in your app. If you put the check in the app delegate in `applicationWillEnterForeground` or `applicationDidBecomeActive` each time that the user enter again in the app the first thing that the app does is checking. Why you should need other way? I think there is not reason to do this when the user do this also because is not possible. But i repeat, there is not reason really!